# How do I use a Haskell type constructor as an enumeration?

Tags: haskell, types, type-constructor

I am writing a program in Haskell that makes use of a lookup table.

eg.

```
type Table = [(Object, FilePath)]
data Object = Player { pName :: String }
```

I want to construct this in such a way that `Player` can be a lookup key:

```
[(Player, "data/players"), ...]
```

If I added another `Object` type `Monster`, my table might look like:

```
[(Player, "data/players"), (Monster, "data/mons"), ...]
```

However, my type definition of a `Table` suggests that I am looking up instantiated objects when, really, I just want to check if it's one type constructor or the other.

How do I go about doing this?

EDIT:

I suppose I want something like:

```
data ObjectType = Player | Monster | ...
```

but is there a way to avoid duplication of the data constructor and type constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't really do this in the way you describe. Because `Player` takes an argument (`pName`), the type of `Player` itself is `String -> Object`, so it won't fit in your `Table` type properly.

As suggested in your edit, you should probably make a separate enumeration type without arguments specifically for `Table`:

```
data ObjectType = PlayerType | MonsterType | ...
```

Depending on how the other constructors of `Object` will be defined, you might be able to avoid duplication, e.g.

```
data Object = Object { objectType :: ObjectType, name :: String }
```

but that does assume that every kind of `Object` will have exactly one `name` argument and nothing else.

EDIT:

On reflection, I wonder if having a lookup table structure makes sense in the first place. You could replace the table with this:

```
lookupPath :: Object -> String
lookupPath (Player {}) = "data/players"
lookupPath (Monster {}) = "data/mons"
...
```

This format will make it harder to do things like persisting the table to disk, but does exactly capture your intention of wanting to match on the object without its parameters.

(The `Player {}` format for the match is the best way to match on constructors that may acquire more arguments in future, as it saves you from having to update the matching code when this happens.)

Comment: I think it's the only reasonable way to approach this.

Comment: I went with your edit since it makes more sense (for me) to pattern match (for now).